# Clicking Push Notification when app is open causes it to crash with 'Window was already created' .net8

Tags: maui, .net-8.0

I have set up Push Notification on my app.

When I click the notification with the app open it crashes:

```
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Window was already created
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.Microsoft.Maui.IWindow.Created() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Window\Window.cs:line 491
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.AppHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<OnConfigureLifeCycle>b__2_0(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Hosting\LifecycleEvents\AppHostBuilderExtensions.Android.cs:line 23
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<OnPostCreate>b__0(OnPostCreate del) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiAppCompatActivity.Lifecycle.cs:line 61
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.InvokeLifecycleEvents[OnPostCreate](IServiceProvider services, Action`1 action) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\LifecycleEvents\LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.cs:line 31
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity.OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiAppCompatActivity.Lifecycle.cs:line 61
[mono-rt]    at DailyBudgetMAUIApp.MainActivity.OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in C:\Users\darre\OneDrive\Documents\OneDrive\Documents\DailyBudgetMAUIApp\DailyBudgetMAUIApp\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs:line 20
[mono-rt]    at Android.App.Activity.n_OnPostCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:line 4488
[mono-rt]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 125
```

I can see that it is crashing in OnPostCreate and obviously cause a window already exists but this is where I get stuck, have tried googling and as much tinkers as I can but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to your error message, you can try to override the `CreateWindow` method in the `App.xaml.cs` file: `protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState){return new Window(new AppShell());}`, if the problem still cannot be solved, you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help me understand your problem better.

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT thanks, that has worked. I had to remove MainPage = new AppShell(); from the App constructor to make it work but otherwise seems to be working. Will need to test to make sure its not effected anything else I guess. Out of interest what is the major impact of removing the create window base behaviour do you know? Had a look and nothing is jumping out at me other than it is using Activation State in some way?

Comment: The former approach is more commonly used on the MacCatalyst and iOS platforms, For android platform, the better and easier way is to add `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask` in MAUI project ->Platforms -> Android -> Resources -> MainActivity.cs -> [Activity( )]. The role of `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask` is to ensure that there is only a single instance of the activity in a task. If an instance of the activity already exists in a task, the system will reuse the existing instance rather than creating a new one.

Comment: When I set the LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, if I click the notification while I have the app open it does not seem to process the pending intent that from the message. I am sure it is something I am missing but I spent a good bit of time trying to make the singleTask LaunchMode work but could not. May be because I am calling the processing of the Intent in OnResume() in MainActivity.cs but couldn't find another method to place it in that would work.

Comment: Please provide the code for how you set up the push notification part. Will the same situation occur if you run the MAUI project on other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ActivityFlags of the intent you set in your Push Notification.
I only had `ActivityFlag.ClearTop` an encountered the same error.

I then changed it to `intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue app was crashing on tap of notification if app is opened by taping another notification,

I fixed with this: Goto> App.xaml.cs and do this change:

```
public partial class App : Application
 {
     public App()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         // MainPage = new AppShell();//<-- //commented to fix EXP: Window was already created on notif tap
     }

     //add bellow function to fix EXP: Window was already created on FCM notif tap
     protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
     {
         return new Window(new AppShell());
     }

 }
```